# Creating image masks in flutter

Tags: flutter

Flutter provides several ways for masks based on paths i.e. clip paths. I am trying to figure out a way where one could take an image with transparency layer like example below and use that image to mask another image / view or as a general mask.

My first instinct was to look at [CustomPaint class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html), but I can't figure it out past this initial idea.

[image]

Comment: see `Paint#blendMode` property

Comment: @pskink after some digging `BlendMode.dstIn` looks like exactly what I was looking for! Thank you, do you want to write up answer about this for others so I can accept it?

Comment: go ahead, write a self-answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flutter has [BoxDecoration class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html) that takes in [BlendMode enum](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode.html). By utilising these you can achieve various mask effects using images, for my particular case above `dstIn` was a solution.

Comment: @lija could you please give us an example. I'm having problem to mask two images.

Comment: an example would do great as it isn't clear which component was used for the image and for the mask.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted an answer to my own same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60470034/1866373), using a custom painter class with a squircle mask and image.

```
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (image != null && mask != null) {
      var rect = Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 200, 200);
      Size outputSize = rect.size;
      Paint paint = new Paint();

      //Mask
      Size maskInputSize = Size(mask.width.toDouble(), mask.height.toDouble());
      final FittedSizes maskFittedSizes =
          applyBoxFit(BoxFit.cover, maskInputSize, outputSize);
      final Size maskSourceSize = maskFittedSizes.source;

      final Rect maskSourceRect = Alignment.center
          .inscribe(maskSourceSize, Offset.zero & maskInputSize);

      canvas.saveLayer(rect, paint);
      canvas.drawImageRect(mask, maskSourceRect, rect, paint);

      //Image
      Size inputSize = Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble());
      final FittedSizes fittedSizes =
          applyBoxFit(BoxFit.cover, inputSize, outputSize);
      final Size sourceSize = fittedSizes.source;
      final Rect sourceRect =
          Alignment.center.inscribe(sourceSize, Offset.zero & inputSize);

      canvas.drawImageRect(
          image, sourceRect, rect, paint..blendMode = BlendMode.srcIn);
      canvas.restore();
    }
  }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is example that converts any white pixel in the mask image to transparent in the main image.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

Image? _image;

Future<void> _loadImage(String maskPath, String imgPath) async {
  ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(maskPath);
  List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
  img.Image mask = img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(bytes))!;
  data = await rootBundle.load(imgPath);
  bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
  img.Image image = img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(bytes))!;
  for (int y = 0; y < mask.height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < mask.width; x++) {
      if (mask.getPixel(x, y) == img.getColor(255, 255, 255, 255)) {
        image.setPixel(x, y, img.getColor(0, 0, 0, 0));
      }
    }
  }
  _image = Image.memory(Uint8List.fromList(img.encodePng(image!)));
}
```

```yaml
dependencies:
  image: ^3.0.1
```